# Nested Git submodules not cloning properly with --recursive flag

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm setting up an internal mirror of a github project. The project has submodules in it, which also have submodules within the original submodules.

I've mirrored all of the repositories individually, and have updated the .gitmodules files in all of the repositories to point to the internal mirror locations. All of the repositories clone individually with --recursive without any issues. For some reason, when I try to clone any repository that has nested submodules, the first set of submodules is read correctly from .gitmodules and cloned, but then the submodules within that submodule will all try to clone from their original github URLs. I can't figure out where these URLs are coming from, because the nested submodules have all had their .gitmodules files updated.

Has anyone ran into this before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing initial setup with  `git submodule update --init --recursive` you're taking the `.gitmodules` values straight from the recorded commits.  I'm thinking when you updated the `.gitmodules` files you didn't do it depth-first, so while the `.gitmodules` recorded in the first-level submodule was updated and added, its own submodules hadn't yet been updated and added so the recorded commit still had the original `.gitmodules` file.

Comment: All of the submodules have had their .gitmodules file updated. I never ran git submodule update --init --recursive. Do I need to do this step? I can't find any good overview on how to do this via google

Comment: [The docs for `git clone --recursive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---recursive) say "This is equivalent to running `git submodule update --init --recursive` immediately after the clone is finished."

Comment: I see - I figured out my issue. The submodules were all referencing a SHA that was earlier than my check-ins to update the .gitmodule files. I had to checkout the correct SHA at each level, check it back in, and then git submodule update --init --recursive worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to do this:

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: No - the clone for any of the nested submodules tries to clone from github, and not my internal mirror. It's like the clone isn't using the head revision for the submodules, and is getting the old version of the .gitmodules file